# Change color of single word in react native textinput

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

Is it possible to change the color of a single word within a textinput in react native?

For example, when mentioning someone in a textinput when commenting:

```
Hello @user
```

I would like "@user" to be a different color than "Hello" **already in the textinput**. I know for `<Text>`, it can be done with `react-native-hyperlink` and `linkify-it`, but this question concerns `<TextInput>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: No, it is not possible using the `<TextInput/>` in React Native.

Your best bet would be using an input mask, something like [react-native-text-input-mask](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-text-input-mask)